# file-uploader: is it possible to add a submit button instead of sending synchronously

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using this jQuery plugin: `https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/` And per default it doesn't have a submit button so i'm trying to find a way to add this (not manually if possible). Here is what i've tried till now..

```
    <form id="drop-zone" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" action="/path/to/page" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="fileuploader">
                <input name="files" type="file">
            </div>  
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        $('input[name="files"').fileuploader({                      
        theme: 'dragdrop',
        extensions: ['xml'],            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways..
One example

you can add a hidden button and call it(you will not see the button):

```
      <input name="files" onChange="document.getElementById('simple').click()" type="file">
     <button type="submit" hidden="true" id="simple"></button>
```

you can add some javascript event too:

```
 <script>
   function submitted(){
       alert('Success!');
       }
 </script>      

     <input name="files" onChange="document.getElementById('simple').click()" type="file">
     <button type="submit" hidden="true" id="simple" onClick="submitted()"></button>
```

But there are some other forms/ways.. 
If you have some specific idea you can ask us again.